# In the JMeter Summary report, I would like to display the average of all the repeated requests instead of individual samples

Tags: jmeter, report, reporting, summary

I have a test plan that runs with 100 threads, and many APIs are repeated in the test flow. I want the Summary CSV report to display the average response time, as seen in the UI.
Currently i shows for example -

[image]

i want the report to display just as seen in UI
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a CSV version of the Summary Report there are 2 ways of getting this:

1. There is a button called "Save Table Data" at the bottom of the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener

   [image]
2. If you want to do this in an unattended/automated manner there is [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) which can generate the summary CSV out of the .jtl results file:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv summary.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but i am generating the report from non-gui and the report name contains current time which i have configured in summary report so i am getting error like unable to find jtl file

Comment: You [should not be using listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) for creating .jtl results file, instead of it you should provide the desired file name and location via `-l` command-line argument. Like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl`. Then the command from the response should work fine. If you want to add timestamp to the file refer to your shell/operating system documentation. More information: [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)